# Need to use third party JS object in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am using Cookiebot library for cookie consent popup in my site, I have added it using script tag (and not using npm and that is the only way to do it as of now). Please note that most of my code is TypeScript.
I need to call the some functions at resize event which are present in cookiebot object,

Is there a way to access Cookiebot object or it's function from TS.

To do so I need to access cookiebot object from the TS code. if i try to access cookiebot through window object 
`window.Cookiebot.show();`
it is giving me error(Property Cookiebot does not exists on type windows), and i can not use it directly like this: 
`Cookiebot.show()` it gives(can not find object Cookiebot)

```
window.addEventListener('resize',function (e){
    if(getInitialWindowWidth != window.innerWidth) {
        doAdjustWidth();
        window.Cookiebot.show();
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: A quick fix is to cast your window to any: (window as any).Cookiebot.show();

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use type declarations.
For the most popular js libraries that miss types they can be installed via npm
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/consumption.html

Also you can declare the missing types yourself, like this:

```
declare namespace cookiebot {
  class Cookiebot {
    show(): void;
  }
}

declare const Cookiebot: cookiebot.Cookiebot;
```